# Installing 11.10 on fresh VirtualBox client hangs - how to debug?

Tags: 11.10, installation, virtualbox, ubiquity, alternate

I am trying to create an 11.10 VirtualBox client using the same DVD I used to upgrade my host system. (It happens to be the alternate DVD ISO.)

However, it keeps hanging when the progress bar reaches about 70%. The last command above the progress bar is `log-output -t ubiquity laptop-detect` but this appeared much earlier in the process (the progress bar keeps going and only hangs later).

By searching for symptoms I eventually found out what my specific problem was (see below), but I still don't know how to **find an error message while I'm busy installing** on a fresh VirtualBox.

Are there **logs I can access**, a **command-line mode** I can switch to, or some other means of finding a report of what is going wrong, assuming there is one?

(If it is not possible to do so, please provide some kind of authoritative reference confirming this.)

Comment: see also https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=45959

Comment: funny ... I just got this today, ended up porting to vmware

Comment: I've found a solution but not an answer on how to debug installer issues, so the bounty is still available :)

Comment: ... maybe its just me ... but if you still want help, dont accept your own answer - at least, not until the bounty period has finished.  It looks very much like, the question has been resolved by your good-self.

Comment: @fossfreedom fair enough :)

Answer (score 3):

I tried the following without resolving the problem, but they may be useful to know:

- increasing client HDD space to 9GB (it actually won't install without this)
- increasing client memory to 1GB (apparently there may be problems with only 512MB)
- disabling client network adapter to stop the installer trying to make network connections

In my case, I needed to change my client storage options, which solved the problem with hanging:

**Option 1: ext3**

Ubuntu 11.10 creates an ext4 partition by default. [This `debian-installer` bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debian-installer/+bug/272684) gave me a hint to try an ext3 partition instead. When I did this, the installation completed successfully.

**Option 2 (preferred): Enable host I/O cache**

However, I think a better solution is to create a new client machine and then tick "Enable host I/O cache" on the SATA controller of the client machine (find it under *Storage* on the client machine settings). [[1]](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=36649&start=0) [[2]](http://ubuntuguide.net/virtualbox-4-on-ext4-error-host-io-cache-will-now-be-enabled) When I did this, I could successfully install Ubuntu using the default (ext4) partition options, which I prefer for no other reason than that it is the default.

**Other candidates**

If this didn't help you try:

- checking if you need to [install third-party software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77432/installing-11-10-on-fresh-virtualbox-client-hangs-how-to-debug/80137#80137) (thanks John)
- [running the memory test](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77432/installing-11-10-on-fresh-virtualbox-client-hangs-how-to-debug/79835#79835) on **both** your host and client machines (you'll find the memory test as one of the options in the first menu of the installation CD/DVD) (thanks Barafu)

**How to debug? I don't know.**

I posted here on AU, the [VirtualBox forums](https://forums.virtualbox.org/), and solved it by searching for my specific symptoms. I still don't know how to retrieve error messages from the installer itself.

Comment: Remember to mark this question as answered :)

Comment: @RolandTaylor after some deliberation I'm not going to :D I've clarified what I'm actually looking for (how to debug, rather than the solution to the specific problem I had)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a trouble with physical memory of host machine. I've run memtest on host machine and it passed OK. Then I have run it in VirtualBox and it ended in errors after an hour. Having replaced the suspicious memory bank, I repeated the test overnight to see no problems. 
Before replacement, I could not install Mint.

Comment: did you run memtest before or after installation? if before, can you detail how? thanks!

Comment: Just took a liveCD image with that function. Knoppix, may be, or Panacea.

Comment: just confirmed there is a memory test option on the ubuntu alternate ISO as well (I'm guessing there's one on the normal ISO too)

Answer (score 1):

My installation required the selection of the third party software to enable the wireless adaptor. Should have read the banners more carefully.